# Pulling data out of multiple tabs in excel sheets

Tags: r, excel, loops, import, tidyverse

I have nearly 300 excel sheets in an untidy format that makes it difficult to import data. In the picture below, you'll see an Excel sheet that has three tabs. Each tab is in the same format as the tab shown in the picture.

[image]

I need to complete the following three steps:

**Step 1**: I need to pull the data from each tab in the following cells:

- Column names: A3, C6, C7, C9, C10, C12, C14, C17, C19.
- Row values: B3, F6, F7, F9, F10, F12, F14, F17, F19.

and then move that data around in a data frame so that it looks something like this

| Object ID | a | b | c | d | e | f | g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

**Step 2**: I need to repeat Step 1 across all three tabs in the excel sheet and then merge the data collected from each tab to produce a data frame something like this:

| TabName | Object ID | a | b | c | d | e | f | g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tab1 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Tab2 | 10 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Tab3 | 10 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

**Step 3**:

I then need to repeat Step 1 and 2 for all 300 excel sheets in my working directory and merge all the data from all 300 files into one data frame to look something like this.

| TabName | Object ID | a | b | c | d | e | f | g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tab1 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Tab2 | 10 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Tab3 | 10 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Tab1 | 20 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Tab2 | 20 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Tab3 | 20 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Tab1 | 30 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Tab2 | 30 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Tab3 | 30 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

Does anyone have any idea how I should approach this? I'm really afraid of having to do this work manually. So if there is any code I could use to streamline this process, that would be amazing!

Thank you so much!

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand based on the screenshots, can you share your excel file

Comment: This is definitely doable in R, but what have you tried? As a jumpng off point, I'd suggest 
the package openxlsx or readxl for reading excel sheets. I would read each sheet twice, once to get the objectID and value, then a second to read columns C and F. Then it's a matter of looping, binding, pivoting, combining and so on to get that final table you need.

Comment: ***First***, read this into a normal R `data.frame`, as it looks in the xlsx file. This means that for instance `Plant 1` will be in two consecutive rows, and the next two rows will have `Plant 2`. Blank rows removed. Only after that is working as desired do you think about the next task, which is ... ***Second***, reshape data from the pictures format to what you want. Those are two completely different tasks. The second task is almost certainly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584/3358272 or several other questions on SO dealing with pivoting/reshaping data.

Comment: Given that, what have you tried? Please have a try at task 1, show your code and results, and move on from there. I suggest starting with a package such as `readxl`, `openxlsx`, or its near-companion package `openxlsx2`.

Comment: You may find this package helpful for wrangling these sorts of data shapes. https://github.com/luisDVA/unheadr

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with package `readxl`.
The main function is `read_all_sheets`. It gets the sheets' names, reads each sheet, extracts the relevant data after removing the `NA`'s and puts those values together in a data.frame. Then `rbind`s all such df's.
This function is called in a `lapply` loop for each of the .xlsx files.

```
read_all_sheets <- function(x, col_types) {
  cnames <- c(1L, 3L) |> rev()
  cvalues <- c(2L, 4L) |> rev()
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(x)
  lapply(sheets, \(s) {
    df1 <- readxl::read_excel(
      path = x,
      sheet = s,
      col_names = FALSE, 
      col_types = col_types, 
      skip = 2L
    ) |> suppressMessages()
    nms <- NULL
    for(i in cnames) {
      tmp <- df1[[i]]
      tmp <- tmp[!is.na(tmp)]
      nms <- c(tmp, nms)
    }
    vls <- NULL
    for(i in cvalues) {
      tmp <- df1[[i]]
      tmp <- tmp[!is.na(tmp)]
      vls <- c(tmp, vls)
    }
    m <- matrix(vls, nrow = 1L, dimnames = list(NULL, nms))
    data.frame(TabName = s) |> cbind(m)
  }) |> 
    do.call(rbind, args = _)
}
read_all_xlsx <- function(path = ".", pattern = "\\.xlsx", col_types) {{
  list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx") |>
    lapply(read_all_sheets, col_types) |> 
    do.call(rbind, args = _)
}}

col_types <- c("text", "numeric", "text", "numeric")
# use the function's defaults path and file name pattern
read_all_xlsx(col_types = col_types)
```